# jQuery update from 1.4.4 to 1.8.0 - no more javascript running from ajax insert

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I was using jquery 1.4.4 - deleted this version and like better the newest 1.8.0 as it seems to be faster, I had some scripts that made interference if ran together, therefore I used to load them via ajax, and when response was successful I would remove one of the scripts and insert the other to a div via html()..

There are calls in these scripts that make calls to functions in the page where the scripts load. These functions can't be called anymore when loading via the ajax method. Neither functions in the page that make use of the loaded script via ajax work nor functions of the loaded script when called from the page work in the page.

It used to work just fine with jquery 1.4.4 - I would like to twist the latest jquery to have this work normally.

Comment: So what does your browser's error console say? We cannot help without seeing any code or any error output.

Comment: TypError function_name is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was that document.ready and window.load got broke becasue of calling a function that was not declared.